# Force.com Ide (Eclipse) shortcuts for right click submenu

Tags: apex, ide, eclipse

Is it possible to add shortcut key for the commands like 'Refresh from Server' as shown below (in Eclipse aka force.com IDE)?

[image]

Note: I tried going to Preferences => General => Keys .. doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this a while ago and found that it is not possible.  The implementation of the Force.com IDE plugin doesn't use [commands](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_difference_between_a_command_and_an_action%3F) which is what you'd need to be able to set up a keybinding.  You can get a peek into the implementation if you unzip the eclipse/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.ui_27.0.0.201302151147.jar (possibly a different version number for you) file and look at the plugin.xml file.  Alternatively you can use the [Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) functionality of eclipse to get more information.

You could look into using a more generic [eclipse macro plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/keyboard-macros) and see if that works.