# Eclipse shortcut for "Show in Salesforce Web"

Tags: eclipse

This might be more of an eclipse question than salesforce. However, in eclipse, how do I create a shortcut to show a selected resource in a salesforce web?

Currently, you need to select the resource --> right click --> Force.com --> show in SF web

anyway to cut out a couple of clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is an old question but found a similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13650/force-com-ide-eclipse-shortcuts-for-right-click-submenu) and thought it might be helpful to repost for other users trying to find the answer: it states that since the force.com ide plugin doesn't use commands you are not able to create shortcuts, he also suggested one work around would be to try using a more generic [eclipse macro plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/keyboard-macros).